# Haskell function using Applicative and Functor

Tags: haskell

I have a practice question, where I'm given a function:

```
sequence :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f[a]
sequence = foldr (_hole (:)) (pure [])
```

and the question says:

```
"What type is required for the function that needs to be placed at 
_hole in the following expression? Also give a definition for the 
expression using  and <$> and <*>".
```

I'm having issue understanding what the question is asking. So for what I've tried, i assume that I'm required to specify the operator since it's using foldr so i assume its something like sequence = foldr((+) (:)) (pure[]).

Then for the definition of the expression, i wrote something like:

```
sequence :: <*> f => [f a] -> f[a]
sequence = foldr <$> pure []
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not 100% correct so would appreciate some help on this on any corrections.

Comment: The question is telling you that `_hole` is a function, and then asking you what type it has to have in order for that definition to type-check. Assume everything else in the definition of `sequence` is correct and that you won't change it.  Also, you don't need an implementation for `_hole`.  (Maybe the next question asks about that.  Once you figure out the type, the implementation is pretty easy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exercise wants you to assume that some value `_hole` is defined somewhere, and that the code above type checks. Then, the goal is to determine what would be the type of that `_hole`. Then, it would ask a possible definition for `_hole`.

For instance, if we were given

```
foo :: Int
foo = 3 + _hole
```

the answer should be `_hole :: Int`, since that's what we need to make the code above to work. For the definition `_hole = 2` is OK.

Instead, in

```
foo :: Int -> Bool
foo = const _hole "hello" True
```

then we need `_hole :: Bool -> Int -> Bool` and for instance `_hole = \b i -> b`.

Your own code is more complex, so it's better to write down all the steps:

```
sequence :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f[a]
sequence = foldr (_hole (:)) (pure [])
```

Here `foldr` is used, which (on lists) has type

```
foldr :: (b -> c -> c) -> c -> [b] -> c
```

To type check, the arguments must have type

```
_hole (:) :: b -> c -> c
pure [] :: c
```

the result of `foldr`, being called with only two arguments is

```
sequence :: [b] -> c
```

since this must match the type of `sequence` above, we get

```
[b] = [f a]
c = f [a]
```

Hence, `b = f a` and

```
_hole (:) :: f a -> f [a] -> f [a]
pure [] :: f [a]
```

The `pure []` part type checks as it is. For the other, we need

```
_hole :: (type of (:)) -> f a -> f [a] -> f [a]
```

i.e. since `(:) :: d -> [d] -> [d]` for any `d`, we get

```
_hole :: (d -> [d] -> [d]) -> f a -> f [a] -> f [a]
```

where `d` can be picked arbitrarily. It is "natural", though, to pick `d=a`, so that we get

```
_hole :: (a -> [a] -> [a]) -> f a -> f [a] -> f [a]
```

Now, we need to write a definition `_hole f x y = ??` in terms of `<$>` and `<*>`. Essentially, we need to re-implement `liftA2` from the library. You should now be able to solve this last part.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step by step, gradually discovering the types of the entities involved in our definition. We are given

```
sequence :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f [a]               --  (1)
sequence = foldr (_hole (:)) (pure [])                    --  (2)
```

so that `sequence = mksequence g` for some `g`:

```
mksequence g xs = foldr (g (:)) (pure []) xs              --  (3)

mksequence g [a,b,...,n] = r where                        --  (4)
    r = g (:) a $ g (:) b $ ... $ g (:) n (pure [])       --  (5)

mksequence g [a] = g (:) a (pure [])                      --  (6)

mksequence g []  = pure []                                --  (7)

-- [a,b,...,n] :: [f a]                     <-(4,1)       --  (8)
--  a,b,...,n  ::  f a                      <-(8)         --  (9)
--  r          :: f [a]                     <-(4,1)       --  (10)
-- pure []     :: f [a]                     <-(7,1)       --  (11)
-- g (:)       :: f a -> f [a] -> f [a]     <-(6,8,11,1)
```

Finally, we've found the type of `g (:)`! Compare it with

```
(<*>)  :: f (a -> t) -> f a -> f t          , _A :: f (a -> t)
(_A <*> _C)                 :: f t          , _C :: f  a
(_B <*> _C)                 :: f (t -> s)   , _B :: f (a -> (t -> s))
((_B <*> _C) <*> _D)        :: f       s    , _D :: f        t
```

So that we have,

```
\ _B _C _D -> ((_B <*> _C) <*> _D)  
          :: f (a -> (t  ->  s)) -> f a -> f  t  -> f  s
   g ((:) ::    a -> [a] -> [a]) :: f a -> f [a] -> f [a]
```

The signatures nearly match! With just a little nudge we have

```
g (:) = (\ _B _C _D -> ((_B <*> _C) <*> _D)) (pure (:))
```

and so, generalizing,

```
g  f2  fa  ft  =  pure f2  <*>  fa  <*>  ft
```

because `(<*>)` associates to the left. Re-checking the types,

```
g  f2  fa  ft  =  pure f2  <*>  fa  <*>  ft
               =       f2  <$>  fa  <*>  ft

-- fa                 :: f a
-- f2                 ::   a -> t -> s
-- f2 <$> fa          :: f     (t -> s)
-- ft                 :: f      t
-- (f2 <$> fa) <*> ft :: f           s
```

In fact this definition already exists, and is named `liftA2` -- for "lifting" a binary function (`f2`) into an applicative "context" (`f`):

```
           f2 ::   a ->   t ->   s
    liftA2 f2 :: f a -> f t -> f s
```